# JAX-WS with async servlets

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, soap, asynchronous

So, I have this old legacy JAX-WS service, that does a lot of IO per request, so each request takes quite a bit of time, but doesn't consume much CPU/RAM.

With amount of clients increasing lately, there's a huge problem of thread starvation.

At first, I thought about implementing JAX-WS builtin async support, but it requires clients to be aware of it, and thats a no in my situation. I cannot possibly force them all to update their code.

My current idea is to create special async servlet and manually parse SOAP request and encode the response, but I can't seem to find some good way to do that.

Is there any way to utilize Servlet 3.1 async support when handling JAX-WS requests?

I should clarify, that I cannot use some kind of queue, or otherwise "just return early", because request processing can fail, and client must get that failure.

Comment: Why you need servlet to handle JAX-WS?

Comment: Because I want to handle request asynchronously, like in https://webtide.com/servlet-3-1-async-io-and-jetty/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution that works perfectly for me, CXF Continuations API.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/continuations.html

https://github.com/search?l=java&q=ContinuationProvider&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

I had to enable async for CXF Servlet, and add jboss module dependency to bundled CXF.

While the whole things feels somewhat like a hack, it allowed me to do proper asynchronous processing without changing service external API at all.
As a bonus, I can even decide whether to suspend request, or process it normally, which helps a lot in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of workflow here where say you have webserver's workers accept the request, you handle it and places it in a queue which is shared by thread which will process this event asynchronously.

This would just mean that you have low wait time on client side and you process the client request asynchronously. In that way, you build your system scalable and can increase number of worker threads on either of the side i.e. webserver so you could accept multiple requests from client concurrently and at the same time multiple threads may be concurrently processing the events from client.

Comment: That's actually one of the things I immediatily thought of.
There's the problem though, that request processing can fail, and client must get that failure as a response.

Comment: Isn't that synchronous request/response that you need? Unless your client can process response asyncly.

Comment: I want my clients to continue using service as if it's synchronous, but use async processing on the server side. For example, look at how Play! framework operates, where clients send good old http requests, but processing can be done asynchronously with Future's and all that.